# Disable Checkbox on selecting another checkbox in mvc4

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-4

I have 3 checkboxes and how I can disable remaining two checkboxes on selecting one checkbox
My code is

```
model
public bool checkbox1{get; set;}
public bool checkbox2{get; set;}
public bool checkbox3{get; set;}

View

@Html.CheckBoxFor(m=>m.checkbox1)
@Html.CheckBoxFor(m=>m.checkbox2)
@Html.CheckBoxFor(m=>m.checkbox3)
```

When I select checkbox 1, remaining 2 checkboxes should be disabled and vice versa. I am new to programming. can u help me out using javascript

Comment: You should try a few things and if you can't figure it out, post your attempts along with what happened instead of what you wanted.

Comment: Handle the jquery [.change()](http://api.jquery.com/change/) event, and use jquery [.prop()](http://api.jquery.com/prop/) to disable all checkboxes except the selected one. Note: disabling a check box means in wont post back so the other 2 properties will be `false`

Comment: Please review the [help section](http://stackoverflow.com/help) to understand what is an acceptable question. SO is not a code writing service.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this?
http://jsfiddle.net/6tdhm4p2/1/

```
$('.checkbox').change(function(){
    $(this).is(':checked')?$(this).siblings('.checkbox').prop('disabled',true):"";
});
```

Comment: could write: ``$(this).siblings('.checkbox').prop('disabled',this.checked)``

Comment: @Ehsan's version is better because it re-enables the checkboxes when the checked one is unchecked.