# How do I disable a checkbox when another checkbox is ticked & re-enable when unticked?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc

I am currently using Javascript to try attempt this, could it be the way I am linking the checkbox to the script? If so any advice would be helpful. Edit- The checkboxes are within a foreach loop and radio boxes will not work as this is not the exact situation I am using this in.

**Checkboxes**

```
@Html.CheckBoxFor(modelItem => item.ambassador, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "checkbox", type = "checkbox" })

@Html.CheckBoxFor(modelItem => item.groupSelection, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "checkbox", type = "checkbox" })
```

**Javascript**

```
<script>
    $('.checkbox').change(function () {
        $(this).siblings('.checkbox').prop('disabled', this.checked);
    });
</script>
```

The Javascript code is from this question: [Disable Checkbox on selecting another checkbox in mvc4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29160697/disable-checkbox-on-selecting-another-checkbox-in-mvc4)

Comment: doesn't that work?

Comment: Not related, but remove `new { type = "checkbox" }` - the `CheckBoxFor()` already add that

Comment: Is your script after the html for the checkboxes (immediately before the closing `</body>` tag)?

Comment: Surely you want to use radio buttons, not check boxes.

Comment: And your code suggests this is in a loop using a `foreach` loop which means it will not bind correctly (refer [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30094047/html-table-to-ado-net-datatable/30094943#30094943) for an explanation)

Comment: @StephenMuecke Huh? It's in a change listener callback function

Comment: @mhodges, Binding has nothing to do with the script (I just pointing out that the code will not bind to OP's model when they submit)

Comment: And the script works fine - refer [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dm68op78/)

Comment: The script is after the html for the checkboxes and I am not using any body or header tags, it is done in cshtml.

Comment: The fiddle proves your code works - clicking on one of the checkboxes will disable the other one. What problem are you having?

Comment: You are right before, this is in a foreach loop which is probably why the it is not linking to the script correctly.

Answer (score 0):

HTML already has a built-in for this, they're called [radio buttons](http://html.com/input-type-radio/):

```html
<form>
  <input type="radio" name="option" value="first">
  <label for="first">first</label>
  <input type="radio" name="option" value="second">
  <label for="second">second</label>
</form>
```

From [EchoEcho](http://www.echoecho.com/htmlforms10.htm):

> Radio buttons are used when you want to let the visitor select one - and just one - option from a set of alternatives. If more options are to be allowed at the same time you should use 
>   check boxes instead.

Because you only want the user to be able to select one of the two options at a time, you should use radio buttons.

See also [this ux.SE post on the subject.](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/41924/is-it-acceptable-practice-to-use-checkboxes-as-radio-buttons)

Answer (score 0):

maybe your checkboxes are being loaded after the script is loaded.. ajax? partial? try adding the listener to your `body` or a parent element

```js
$(function(){
  $('body').on('click', '.checkbox', function () {
    $(this).siblings('.checkbox').prop('disabled', this.checked);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input class="checkbox" type="checkbox"></input> check 1<br>
<input class="checkbox" type="checkbox"></input> check 2<br>
<input class="checkbox" type="checkbox"></input> check 3<br>
<input class="checkbox" type="checkbox"></input> check 4<br>
```